# Простой вопрос про hover css

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! Допустим есть пару блоков, к которым нужно добавить `cursor pointer` при наведении, и ничего больше.

Так вот, как "правильнее" посоветуют делать опытные верстальщики. Создать отдельный класс `.hover:hover { cursor: pointer }` и добавлять его к классам `div class="block1 hover"`,

Или же делать перечисление в CSS? `.div1:hover, .div2:hover, div3:hover { cursor: pointer }`

Comment: классы это вам не id

Answer (score 4):

я бы сделал так -

```
    .hover { cursor: pointer }
```

без псевдокласса :hover, мне кажется он здесь лишний

Comment: Так подождите. Что-то я туплю. А как без псевдокласса hover указать, что это стили для элемента с классом .hover, **на который навели**?

Comment: @smellyshovel, встречный вопрос - а что вообще делает `cursor`? И самое главное - как сильно он влияет на отображение элемента, пока курсор на него не навели?) Я уже даже не спрашиваю о том, сколько у Вас единовременно разных курсоров может отображаться на экране.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский да, понял, о чем вы. Иногда такие "затупы" происходят. Сейчас свой ответ предложу.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский а хотя нет, автор ответа, по сути, это уже сделал.

Answer (score 0):

Не советую добавлять лишние бесполезные классы. Используйте какую-нибудь методологию.

Например, согласно [БЭМ](https://en.bem.info/methodology/) методологии - [недопустимо создавать класс как модификатор](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/#block). Поэтому я бы рассмотрел цель этого класса `hover` и переработал каждый из необходимых `div1`, `div2`, `div3` на предмет схожести целей. Если это кнопки - ну так и сделайте блок `button` и вставляйте туда все необходимые стили. И плодите эти блоки на странице сколько душе угодно (переиспользуемость).

Если так каждое CSS-свойство объединять, то у вас будут миллионы классов на теге а-ля `<div class="block1 hover black-text white-bg size-22 ..."></div>`, что, естественно, не есть хорошо.